# How to initialise Redux store in react native with a StackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am creating a react-native app with react-navigation.

Now I ant to implement Redux in my app but I don't know how this works exactly. I created my stacknavigator like this:

`const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({Start: {screen: Start}});`

Then I needed the documentation says asks to use `createAppContainer(MainNavigator)` and `AppRegistry.registerComponent()`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MainNavigator />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```